# Extracting pecentage values from Data Frame in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, percentage

I have this DF where I have percentage values.

[image]

I need to extract Country and Sample Share Used (which is percentage) in a separate DF. I do that like so,

[image]

but I get completely different percentage values where there is not even the percentage sign.

[image]

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?